# Mongodb Hacking

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8d9dfc16ae887c03502c49"),
    "btc" : "187NRsDZ9QVcYLKopd2F46C2fbSGfR29Ru",
    "info" : "Your data is a backed up. You must pay 0.1 BTC to 187NRsDZ9QVcYLKopd2F46C2fbSGfR29Ru 72 hours for recover it. After 72 hours expiration we will leaked and exposed all your data. Need any proofs? shaechah@tfwno.gf or shaechah@secmail.pro You are welcome!"
}
```

I recently setup mongodb and as for development purposes my database is been hacked. By unknown hacked that wants me to send 0.1 btc to btc wallet.

My Question is how to properly secure mongodb database.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Follow this checklist: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/

Comment: Most importantly: 1) don't expose MongoDB to the Internet unless you really need it, either make it listen only on localhost if your application is on the same server as the DB or configure your server's firewall to your application server's IP otherwise (for dev access you can always SSH into the server and forward the DB port to your machine), and 2) enable authentication and set a username/password

Comment: it wasn't hacked though, you left it open